# Dynamic hyperlinking in a pdf

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

Firstly, pardon me for creating the question named "Dynamic Hyperlinking", I had to do it because I do not know what is the correct technical term for it.

The problem is this, lets say I have a pdf with a hyperlink, this hyperlink points to a file in the same folder as the pdf file (../file).

Let's say the path of the pdf and the file is `C:\Folder1\`. Now if I change the location or modify the path to `C:\NewFolder` (for both the files), I still want the hyperlink to work correctly.

Any guidance on this (also the correct technical term for what I want to do) is appreciated.

Regards,

babsdoc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically, you could use the app.openDoc() Acrobat JavaScript method, which allows for relative paths.

Manually, you would use the Open Document action, or simply create a link to the target document. Here, you may, however, have to verify if the path is relative.